# Python sort data and load to excel

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, sorting

I am working on a task in which I scan 1000+ emails of candidates and assign points based on their relevance as per requirement. I want to export this data to excel but in sorted order. Sorting order would be, the profile with maximum points (the most relevant profile) should go on top (order by points desc). I have python 3.3.5 on windows 7 32 bit.

I searched and understood that I might need pandas module to store the data in a dataframe and then sort that on my column and load into excel file. I then tried installing pandas using

```
pip install pandas
```

on both cmd as well cmd (run as administrator) but it gives an error -

```
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in c:\users\sanket~1
\appdata\local\temp\pip-build-ihqwe4\pandas\
```

can someone please help me on this sorting issue and suggest how can I resolve installation error of pandas? Or is there any other way to sort the data?

Comment: Try `pip install pandas --user`, and you don't need admin privileges.

Comment: If that doesn't work, use pre-built wheels from the following [site](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/). Make sure to grab the right version for your interpreter/architecture.

Comment: No luck, same error - 
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in c:\users\sanket~1
\appdata\local\temp\pip-build-60tv1w\pandas\

Comment: Try using the wheel install. Use `pip install name_of_wheel.whl`. Do not rename the wheel (it is filename-sensitive). The downloaded wheel must be in the same directory as your CLI working directory.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why you need pandas to do this. I would just store them as a sorted `list` of `(score,candidate)` tuples and then just write as a CSV:

```
tuples = ... # read your dataset as a list of (score,candidate) tuples
tuples.sort(reverse=True) # will sort by first element of tuples (score) in descending order
f = open('output.csv','w')
for e in tuples:
    f.write("%s,%s" % e)
f.close()
```

The resulting CSV file can be opened in Excel

Comment: Not so simple.... CSV has quoted values, and escape characters. This will not work for some CSV data. You should use the CSV module rather than some ad-hoc attempt. I would strongly recommend using an actual library (such as `csv`, or `libxlsxwriter`, or `OpenPyXL`, or `pandas`) to do this.